# How many partitions can windows handle if you include Linux

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, windows-vista, multi-boot

Am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows Vista. So far I have three primary partitions (windows) (Eisa) (Recovery). How many Linux partitions (root, home, swap) can I create on free space without running into a conflict with Windows? I haven't been able to find specific answers for that when I search.

Comment: All but very, very old Linux distros will boot from a logical partition. If the drive is an IDE drive that means you can use up to 63 (this was lowered to 15 for SATA drives). I would share the swap and home partitions between all of them though. With EFI/GPT you get several more advantages, the limit is up to 128 logical partitions and you can have those each be > 2TB.

Comment: There isn't a limit unless your limited to MBR partitions.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, there's no reason to separate root and home into two different partitions.

Comment: @Mew: One reason: simplifies upgrading the OS without touching your user files.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/894605/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-os-that-can-be-installed-in-a-hard-disk-drive#comment1197513_894605.  See the link in the comment to another SU question that explains the partition limits in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GPT and UEFI, you're not going to have a problem. It just works.

MBR is tricky, though, as it has a cap of 4 Primary partitions. Fortunately, you can get around this by creating what's called an "Extended Partition." These things can contain almost infinite other partitions.

When you use the Ubuntu install disk, load up GParted and make all the free space you want. In that free space, make an Extended partition with maximum possible size. Then, place your EXT and Swap (about equal to your memory) in the extended partition. Run the Installer and select "something else" when asked about partitions. Choose the EXT partition and make that your `/` mount point.